# How to upgrade an offline computer's OS and software?

Tags: linux, security, updates

I have a Linux computer that is kept offline for extra security.

How do I keep it up to date without putting it online?

It's running Fedora 17, but I don't mind changing to another distribution if that's what it takes to be able to perform offline updates.

Comment: Inherently, an offline computer will not be able to download updates automatically, so you could burn an update disk and install if from the CD

Comment: @wolfo9999 Right, but how is that done? How to create an "update disk"?

Comment: That depends on the distrobution you are running. Ubuntu has regular full system updates that can be burnt onto a disk. This would work in an offline situation. Some distros use a rolling release, meaning packages are updated individually. In that case, you probably cannot update it without internet access.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify your question adding details about which distribution it's running, and what version.

Comment: @slhck Yes, done.